# Реляционная БД — где хранить счётчики (кол-во комментариев, кол-во лайков)?

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server, архитектура, структуры-данных

В базе данных есть Записи, у которых могут быть Лайки и могут быть Комментарии. Нужно отобразить список Записей и для каждой Записи отобразить кол-во Лайков и Комментариев.

[image: структура базы данных]

Собственно, как это лучше сделать? Я вижу три варианта (не считая вариантов использования кэша, вроде Redis):

1. Запрашиваем список Записей и для каждой записи запрашиваем COUNT Лайков и Комментариев. Но это как-то слишком затрано, по-моему. Будет много запросов к базе.
2. Сохраняем кол-во Лайков и Комментариев в таблице Записей. Придётся добавить дополнительную логику, но мне такой вариант нравится больше всего.
3. Создаём ещё одну таблицу PostInfo, в которой будем хранить кол-во Лайков и Комментариев для конкретной Записи. При запросе Записей делаем JOIN к этой таблице. Так, наверное, правильнее всего будет, так как Записям не нужно знать о кол-во Лайков и Комментариев.

Comment: Если пользователя удаляют, его лайк остаётся, или должен быть удалён вместе с ним?

Comment: @i-one Лайк остаётся. Да и возможность удаления пользователя не предусмотрена. Только удаление поста.

Comment: второй вариант с отдельной таблицей

Comment: Посмотрите, как это реализовано на [StackOverflow][1]. Тут можно и запросы посоставлять. [1]:https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new

Answer (score 5):

В SqlServer вариант 1 можно реализовать с помощью *materialized view*, в этом случае по затратности он будет приближаться к третьему варианту.

Создаём представление:

```
create view dbo.LikeCount
with schemabinding
as
    select post_id, Cnt = count_big(*)
    from dbo.Like
    group by post_id
GO
```

Добавляем индекс, материализующий представление:

```
create unique clustered index IX_LikeCount on dbo.LikeCount (post_id)
GO
```

Аналогичное представление можно создать для таблицы `Comment`. После чего можно запрашивать данные следующим образом:

```
select p.id, p.title, isnull(lc.Cnt, 0) as LikeCnt, isnull(cc.Cnt, 0) as CommentCnt
from Post p
    left join LikeCount lc with (noexpand) on lc.post_id = p.id
    left join CommentCount cc with (noexpand) on cc.post_id = p.id
```

Удобство такого варианта в том, что при изменении данных в таблицах `Comment` и `Like` количества будут автоматически пересчитываться (в вариантах 2 и 3 эту логику придётся реализовывать специально - в триггерах, или процедурах/запросах, которые работают с добавлением/удалением лайков и комментариев).

Минус в том, что для лайков и комментариев представления раздельные, в следствие чего дополнительных соединений в запросе два (в варианте 3 оно будет одно, а в варианте 2 его вообще не будет). Также, если есть вероятность, что в будущем может потребоваться удалять пользователей, оставляя лайки, то этот вариант не подойдёт, и лучше смотреть в сторону вариантов 2 и 3.

Вариант 2 выгоднее для `select` (в запросе не потребуется дополнительное соединение для вытаскивания количеств лайков и комментариев). Вариант 3 лучше с точки зрения независимости постов от сопутствующих им количеств (если происходит изменение записи, соответствующей какому-то посту, и в это же время кому-то вздумалось лайкнуть эту запись, то эти два действия не будут блокировать друг-друга).

Answer (score 4):

По-моему, надо исходить из использования:

- *хранить* лучше в нормализованной схеме, т.е. 1-й вариант;
- *читать* быстрее из единого места: чтобы пост + счетчики (2-й вариант).

Минус второго варианта в том, что *вычисляемые* данные хранятся для всех записей, в то время, как реально требуется только вершина айсберга – свежие записи, которые читают/запрашивают.

Поэтому **решение – кэш**, тот же Redis, в котором держать записи+счетчики, а в БД – только данные по 1-му варианту.

В кэше ограничить время жизни записи. При чтении искать в кэше, если нет, то дергать БД и писать в кэш. При новом лайке/комментарии обновлять БД и кэш, если запись в кэше ещё присутствует.

Answer (score 0):

Во втором и третьем случае вы рискуете получить веселенькие грабли с синхронизацией всех этих счетчиков. Пока вы - не фейсбук, наиболее простым будет вариант 1.

Comment: Если вести сами лайки отдельной таблицей и синхронизировать количества в таблицу пользователей триггерами - то проблем с синхронизацией не будет.